# What is the difference between if checks at same time and if checks after at least one if check was passed?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Can someone of you explain me in which case I should do all if-checks at the same time or make if-checks in a if-check?

When should I do it like in example 1 and when should I do it like in example 2?

example 1:

```
if ($var1 == condition && $var1 =! ...) // all checks at the same time
{
    ...
}
```

example 2:

```
if ($var1 == condition) // if-check in a if-check
{
    if ($var1 != ...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "if-checks at the same time" isnt exactly what happens here. Look up short circuit operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single if check for multiple conditions allows the following:

- An event when both conditions are met
- An event when neither condition is met

However using an 'if check within an if check' allows the following:

- An event when one condition is met and the other isn't
- An event when both conditions are met
- An event when neither condition is met

Using an 'if check within an if check' allows more flexibility. However, if you only want something to happen if both conditions are met, the first one will suffice.

Example for a single check

```
$var1 = 1
$var2 = 2

if($var1 == 1 && $var2 == 2){
  //code for when var1 is 1 and var2 is 2
}
else{
  //code for when either var1 is not 1 or var2 is not 2
}
```

Example for nested checks

```
if($var1 == 1){
  if($var2 == 2){
    //Code for when var1 is 1 and var2 is 2
  }
  else{
  //code for when var 1 is 1 and var2 is not 2
  }
else{
  //Code for when var1 is not 1 (BUT var2 might be 2)
}
```